# Invalid property ID while building HTML

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

[image]

I'm trying to build a dynamic form on the server side before injecting to client side with apps script.

I have to build the html with strings because there doesn't appear to be a good templating system on the server side with apps script . So far my html looks like:

```
label <select id="DATE" name="DATE" type="text" value="myvalue"/> label <select id="FULLNAME" name="FULLNAME" type="text" value="myvalue"/> label <select id="STREET" name="STREET" type="text" value="myvalue"/>
```

My plan is to replace 'label' with an actual html label which I'm generating using the code in the screenshot

The buildhtml function is:

```
// my little html string builder
function buildHTML(tag, html, attrs) {
  // you can skip html param
  if (typeof(html) != 'string') {
    attrs = html;
    html = null;
  }
  var h = '<' + tag;
  for (attr in attrs) {
    if(attrs[attr] === false) continue;
    h += ' ' + attr + '="' + attrs[attr] + '"';
  }
  return h += html ? ">" + html + "</" + tag + ">" : "/>";
}
```

How can I fix this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"for" is a reserved keyword in JavaScript, because it's used in some kind of a loop. Browsers may let you get away with misusing it as a property Id, but Google Apps Script will not. Put it in quotation marks, which is a good idea with field names anyway, even when not required.

```
{"for": field}
```